# wxPython does not work__import wx generates an error

Tags: python, wxpython

This is a [web tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E6rnfHgyPmM) explaining how to install [wxPython(3rd link from the list is the version that i have installed).](http://sourceforge.net/projects/wxpython/files/wxPython/2.8.11.0/)

Also my Python version is `Python 2.6.2`

Whenever i try to type (according to tutorial)

```
import wx
app=wx.App()
win=wx.Frame(None)
win.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

then `save` it and `run it` i receive the following message in GUI Python Shell:

```
Traceback(most recent call last):
  File "E:/Python26/sdf", line 1, in <module>
   import wx
  File "E:/Python26\wx.py", line 2, in <module>
   app=wx.App()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'App'
```

You can also see it in a pic... [image: pic.]

**Why is this happening while in the tutorial wxPython works flawlesly???**

**How i can bypass this problem??**

Comment: What is your script file's name?

Comment: sdf just that i gave it a random name

Comment: Try going to the python console and typing `import wx` and see if you get the same problem.

Comment: Yes I do i typed it on the GUI and I am still having the same problem

Comment: Not the `IDLE`, try the command line. Go to `cmd`/`sh` and type `python` >> Enter >> `import wx` >> Enter. See what happens

Comment: I typed in the Python command line import wx and i am still getting the same problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you named your script "wx.py" and put it in your root Python directory: C:\Python26. This is part of the search path that Python uses when it imports modules. It finds your wx.py and imports it instead of the real wx package. Save your script with a name that does not conflict with the module you are trying to import.

Comment: Just a sec to check it plz

Comment: Godbless you it works!!! I didn't use any `py` or `pyc` extension while saving it; I just saved it as tuna and no extension. Should I use any extension?

Comment: You should still use the .py extension